# Seasonal Adjustment of columns within dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, seasonal-adjustment

I have a dataframe that contains monthly data on natural gas and oil in storage and CDD/HDD (as part of a larger class project on modeling gas and oil prices). I want to seasonally adjust these 4 columns since the data is seasonal. I am new to R and still am getting use to the logic.

I have tried this

```
install.packages("seasonal")
library(seasonal)
data%>%
    mutate(`sNG Stored` <- seas(`NG Stored`,x11 = ""))
```

and the following error was thrown:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: ``sNG Stored` <- seas(`NG Stored`, x11 = "")`.
Caused by error in `x13_prepare()`:
! 'x' argument is not a time series.
```

Comment: [Please note](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) that supplying a few rows of your dataset would help to make a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seasonal/versions/1.9.0/topics/seas), the function `seasonal::seas()` takes as `x` one of the following types of objects: `ts`, `mts`, or a list of `ts` objects. Based on the error you report, the datafreame column `NG Stored` is not a time series object. For the `seas()` function to run properly, the column `NG Stored` needs to be converted to either a `ts` or `mts`. Your question didn't supply any data, so I created some toy data to illustrate one possible conversion process.

```
library(zoo)
#> Warning: package 'zoo' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric

df <- data.frame(date = as.Date('2022-01-01') + 0:9,
                 values = runif(10, 10, 500) + seq(50, 59)^2)
df
#>          date   values
#> 1  2022-01-01 2519.030
#> 2  2022-01-02 2983.906
#> 3  2022-01-03 2742.768
#> 4  2022-01-04 2998.628
#> 5  2022-01-05 2999.749
#> 6  2022-01-06 3149.857
#> 7  2022-01-07 3468.573
#> 8  2022-01-08 3522.451
#> 9  2022-01-09 3827.004
#> 10 2022-01-10 3716.138
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ date  : Date, format: "2022-01-01" "2022-01-02" ...
#>  $ values: num  2519 2984 2743 2999 3000 ...
tseries <- read.zoo(df)
str(tseries)
#> 'zoo' series from 2022-01-01 to 2022-01-10
#>   Data: num [1:10] 2519 2984 2743 2999 3000 ...
#>   Index:  Date[1:10], format: "2022-01-01" "2022-01-02" "2022-01-03" "2022-01-04" "2022-01-05" ...
class(tseries)
#> [1] "zoo"
tseries_ts <- as.ts(tseries)
class(tseries_ts)
#> [1] "ts"
```

Now the dataframe should be ready to accept the `seas()` function. The base `R` functions `str()` and `class()` are helpful for diagnosing these kinds of issues.

Comment: I have a date column and then 39 columns of data. Can i make them all a ts? If so, can I still plot the data against date in a lineplot on ggplot without giving ggplot an issue since my y-var is now a TS?

Comment: Yes you can make them all `ts`. When I tried to plot the sample data from my answer using `ggplot`, I got an error saying that the object was a `ts` and needs to be a data frame. Therefore, it looks like you'll need to change it back before plotting in `ggplot` and `zoo` has functions for this. Alternatively, you can use a time series plotting library like [`dygraphs`](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/) which does take `ts` data.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I will say I have tried running seas on one of my columns to no avail. These are the two things I tried:

"tseries_ts%>%
  mutate(`sNG Stored` <- seas(`NG Stored`,x11 = ""))" and

"seas(tseries_ts$`NG Stored`)"

Comment: What error does `seas()` return?